# Hyphen in compound word?

Tags: hyphenation, compounds

Better with or without hyphen?

> **Dollar-quotes**
>   Use **dollar-quoted** strings to simplify!
>   Use **dollar-quoting** to simplify!

Does it matter whether the second part is another noun?
And does it make a difference whether the compound word is used as adjective?

(The dollar character `$` can be used to quote strings in the database system PostgreSQL. Hence the technical term. Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/search/?u=%2Fdocs%2F10%2F&q=dollar%20quote).)

Comment: Better with the hyphens, and no to your other questions. The compounds "dollar-quoted" and "dollar-quoting" are verb-centred compound adjectives.

Comment: The answer and the linked site seem to disagree on your first part. And are you sure  "dollar-quoting" serves as adjective in the example?

Comment: Are you asking about hyphens in compounds _in general_, or only about whether "dollar-quote" should use a hyphen or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on context.

1. "Dollar quotes" or "dollar quoting" as a noun phrase:  "Sometimes you need dollar quotes when using Postgresql."
2. "Dollar-quoted" as a compound adjective:  "Dollar-quoted strings simplify your life."

So, your first line depends on if there is even a sentence.  The second line should be hyphenated, and the last line should not be hyphenated.

You may want to review this website: https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp